# How to read .DBX format

Tags: java, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have `.DBX` file which contains tables with data (students, books, other tables and relations between them. Important it's not an email file). I need to retrieve data from it, preferably using Java. How can I do it ? Is it possible ? Or I should convert it into relational structure like tables in `RDBMS`. If yes, then are there any free tools to do it ?  File itself contains just bytes and its size is `65MB`. I attempted to read bytes, but I failed with encoding. And I suppose it's not good idea to obtain complicated data with relations by reading bytes. Any ideas ?

Comment: I used XBaseJ to read .dbf files from Java. There is a new kid in town that claims it can read foxpro too: https://github.com/Yasas/xbase4j/issues/1. You can also check if there is ODBC / JDBC support available

Comment: Instead of saying .DBX, you need to find out what type of file that is first. VFP and alike RDBMS doesn't store all the tables in a single file (but say for example MS access does). First find what that is really.

Answer (score 1):

The .DBX extension is **nothing to do with Visual FoxPro or FoxPro despite multiple incorrect Google results you might see**.

It **is not** the index file for a Visual FoxPro database container (.DBC) as that extension is .DCX, again despite multiple incorrect Google results you might see.

You could maybe try examining the header bytes to find out what it actually is.

Comment: I thought .DBX files were created by outlook express, as Alan said t's definitely not a VFP file

Comment: @Alan B how to read head. My file starts with following bytes:
  
0001 0000 5374 616e 6461 7264 204a 6574
2044 4200 0000 0000 b56e 0362 6009 c255
e9a9 6772 403f 009c 7e9f 90ff 859a 31c5
79ba ed30 bcdf cc9d 63d9 fdc7 9846 4346
04fd b7c9 df03 681e c682 855e 28e6 13b6
8a60 5494 7b36 5678 dfb1 77f4 1343 cfaf
b133 3461 795b 92b5 7c2a 05f1 7c99 011b
98fd 124f 4a94 6c3e 6026 5f95 f8d0 8924
8567 c61f 2744 d2ee cf65 edff 07c7 46a1
7816 0ced e92d 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
..................

Comment: Well according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures it could be a Palm Desktop file.